# Cannot display default NGINX page

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ipv6, ipv4, netplan

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my server. I also installed Nginx.

My problem is that the default sie Nginx page is not displayed. Yet UFW is not activated.

Do you have an idea of the problem ?

> This site is inaccessible 24.76.99.542 took too long to respond. Here
> are a few tips :
>
> Check connection Check proxy and firewall ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Here is the content of the automatically created Netplan file :

nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:2e:93:2c:10
            mtu: 1500
            set-name: ens3
```

When launching Ubuntu displays this :

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Mon Sep  7 03:04:50 UTC 2020

  System load:  0.0               Processes:             117
  Usage of /:   8.4% of 19.21GB   Users logged in:       1
  Memory usage: 5%                IPv4 address for ens3: 84.16.79.142
  Swap usage:   0%


0 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.


*** System restart required ***
Last login: Mon Sep  7 03:01:03 2020 from 45.83.90.147
```

Comment: Check for an external firewall provided by your hosting provider.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you, indeed I had not thought of that

Comment: https://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/2126/opening-ports-in-the-firewall

Answer (score -3):

For ubuntu you will need to enable the firewall using ufw enable command
Add the ports needed using  ufw allow 22/tcp first to access post firewall enabled
then ufw allow 80/tcp or 443/tcp

ufw status will provide you allowed ports

Comment: In the question mentioned, UFW is not activated.